# Pointer magic: structs with pointer members and more

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I really don't have a clue how to give this question a good title - sorry for that.

Just to know what's the goal of all this: pass a uint8_t variable pointer to bar() which does set it to 1 or 0, that I can check it's state inside my main. I do need zbar(), it's a thread and it does actually setting the value to 1 or 0

So I have somewhere:

```
struct foo_t {
    ...
    uint8_t *state;
};
```

and in main I go with:

```
int main(void) {
     uint8_t state = 0;
     bar(&state);

     while(1) {
          if(state)
              //do something here
     }
}
```

and here we have somewhere else in another sourcefile.

```
void bar(uint8_t *state) {
    struct foo_t *foo;    //using malloc here - don't worry

    foo->state = state;

    zbar(foo);
```

}

```
void zbar(struct foo_t *arg) {
    if(condition)
       arg->state = 1;
    else
       arg->state = 0;
 }
```

How to make this working? o0
zBar can actually access the arg struct, that's not the problem at all.

Please don't worry why I do it so strange, it's used within threads etc.

Comment: Your question as it is currently written makes no sense. There's no question in what you wrote, what do you want us to do?

Comment: I want to pass the pointer wich i pass to bar() to zbar, which then does change the value of the variable WITH the address state to 1 or 0, that I can read out state in my main.

I guess the over all question is: How can I access the value of a variable which is a pointer member in a struct where i get the pointer from the struct >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant `void bar(uint8_t* state)`?

It does not do what I think you intended. Again I assume you want the `state` variable in `main` to be changed? If so try

```
struct foo_t {
    uint8_t* state; // changed this to a pointer type.
}

void bar(uint8_t* state) {
    struct foo_t *foo = blah blah;
    foo->state = state;
    zbar(foo);
}

void zbar(foo_t* arg) {
   if (condition)
       *(arg->state) = 1;
   else
       *(arg->state) = 0;
}
```

I *tihnk* this is what you're trying to do

Comment: aaah! That was helpful, thanks for your help :)
and yes, this is what I want to do :D

Answer (score 2):

`bar()` needs to take its parameter via pointer.  Also, if you want to check the state in `main`, you will need to change the pointed-to `bool` after calling `zBar`

```
void bar(uint8_t* state) {
  struct foo_t *foo; //using malloc here - don't worry
  foo->state = *state;
  zbar(foo);
  *state = foo->state;
}
```

You are calling it correctly in `main` (`bar(&state);`)

Note that the way it this code is now, once `zbar` is called, `state` will never change again.  If you want a thread to access (and modify) state, you will need to store the address in `struct foo`:

```
struct foo
{
  // ...
  uint8_t* state;
};
```

And alter `bar`:

```
void bar(uint8_t* state) {
  struct foo_t *foo; //using malloc here - don't worry
  foo->state = state; // no dereferencing
  // zbar(foo);  // start the thread using zbar
}

void zbar(struct foo_t *arg) {
  if(condition)
    *(arg->state) = 1;
  else
    *(arg->state) = 0;
}
```

Then any changes to `*(foo->state)` will also change `state` in `main`

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you're saying is:

- thread 1 runs `main`, and has a local variable `uint8_t state`

  - it will check the value of this local variable in a loop, expecting it may be updated asynchronously by `zbar`
- thread 2 runs (amongst other things) `zbar`

  - when `zbar` changes the value of `arg->state`, you want `main` to see the new value in thread 1

So, firstly, you need to make sure `arg->state` and `main`'s local `state` variable actually refer to the same location in memory. Since `bar` already allocates `foo_t arg`, it might be easier to make that the shared copy:

```
int main(void) {
    foo_t *arg = bar();

    while(1) {
        if(arg->state)
            ; //do something here
    }
}
```

Secondly, you need to make sure that `main` actually *sees* the new value at that location: as **infact** says, there are a couple of things that might prevent this.  Most obviously, there is no requirement for `main` to *ever* reload the value of `state` after the first call to `bar`, because it can't see anything that might change it.

This stuff is inherently non-portable; tell us the platform, and we'll be able to give more information.

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't work. First of all, it won't compile -- `foo_t`'s `state` member is defined to be a `uint8_t` but you are trying to store a `uint8_t *` in it. If you fix this by making `bar` say something like `foo->state = *state`, then it still won't work because although `bar` is being passed a pointer to `main`'s `state` variable, all it does with it is to dereference it once and put the result in a struct.

You could declare `foo_t` to have a `uint8_t *` member, pass `&state` from `main` into `bar` and store that in the `foo_t`. Or (if the structure of your code permits it) forget about the `foo_t` altogether and just pass the pointer to `state` from `main` to `bar` to `zbar`. That is, one of these:

```
struct foo_t { ...; uint8_t * state; ... };
void bar(uint8_t * state) { struct foo_t * foo; ...; foo->state = state; zbar(foo); ... }
void zbar(struct foo_t * arg) { ...; *(arg->state) = 1; ... }
```

[EDITED to add: in this case you also need to declare `state` volatile in `main`, to warn the compiler that another thread might modify its value.]

or

```
void bar(uint8_t * state) { ...; zbar(state); ... }
void zbar(uint8_t * state) { ...; *state = 1; ... }
```

One other remark. "It's used within threads etc." is not a good justification for doing something strange or ugly. If there's a *specific* reason why the *specific* things you're doing with threads require it, of course that's another matter, and of course you're under no obligation to defend your design decisions here -- I just want to caution you against seeing "here be threads" as a *general* licence to do strange things.

Comment: I changed the bar thing in my first post, it was a typo, it takes a uint8_t*.
it needs to take be a struct, because there are also other members in there.
But how can I access actual state's value, where i have the pointer from that in my struct?

Comment: In the code you posted, you don't have a pointer in the struct, you have an actual `uint8_t` value in the struct. The first of the two options I mentioned puts a pointer in the struct and -- if I've understood you correctly -- achieves exactly what you're asking for ... except that I just realised that I didn't show what the code in `main` then needs to do. I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Actually, no, the code in `main` looks just the same as it does now. Except that if `state` might be being changed in another thread, you'd better declare it `volatile` in `main`: `volatile uint8_t state;`.

Comment: (I edited my code to match the edits in the OP, whose code still won't compile but now for a different reason.)